# solve a problem with simulink

Tags: matlab

I have this problem which i want to solve using simulation.
How i think it shall work in Simulink( i am not sure this is the way to do it) :
-measure power and then decrease the voltage and increase R of bulb and measure new power and make difference ...

I found in my library :

```
-the power sensor who says in description
"The block calculates the power taken by the load connected across the + and - terminals under the assumption that only the load is connected to the + terminal. Refer to the block icon for the arrangement of internal current and voltage sensors.

The sensor can return either instantaneous power, or power averaged over a fixed time period. The latter option caters for periodic current and voltage waveforms such as those associated with PWM control."

-lamp
"This block models an incandescent lamp. The resistance is given by R = R0*(1+alpha*deltaT) where R0 is the initial resistance at turn-on, alpha is the resistance temperature coefficient and deltaT is the change in temperature."

-voltage source
```

Connecting the components doesnt give me any usefull data in simulation.

The problem is
[image: Problem]

Here is by hand approach which is cumbersome :D

[image: Hand approach]

Comment: This problem requires a simple calculation. Using a simulator and even Simulink for that matter is totally unnecessary. It's like you're using a machinegun to kill a fly. Total overkill.

Comment: It is true , but I am learning the Simulink tool and i want to do these examples

Comment: If the voltage decreases by 5V the filament temperature will decrease, and so will its resistance. So (without defining "light bulb" as something other than incandescent) the example is nonsense.

Comment: I think you didnt understood the problem ;)

Comment: Why mention an incandescent bulb library when there is no temperature coef information (or temp change) to derive a change in resistance, equally the actual question doesn't call for anything like that. Vote to close due to vagueness

Answer (score 1):

There are four aspects to Matlab:simulink that would facilitate you solving this

1. Simulink
2. Stateflow
3. SimPowerSystems
4. SimElectronics

Any one of these is capable of solving these problems.

Simulink aims to solve problems in the integration domain.

SimPowerSystem's bolts onto Simulink an electrical domain interface

Simscape & Simelectronics, while acting as a bolt on to simulink solve the problem slightly differently.

The fact you mention "power sensor" & the description would imply you are attempting this via SimScape.

If a model is created as such:

[image]

And from the actual question: V=120V  and R=192\$\Omega\$ (from rearrangement of the \$P = \frac{V^2}{R}\$ equation )

I have used a PS->Simulink converter to make use of a DISPLAY sink, otherwise simscape defaults to outputting to the workspace.

So how to solve the question via simulink:Stateflow

Well we could simply change the voltage by -5V and the resistance +8\$\Omega\$ but the question asked for the change, so why not let Stateflow do the work.

Two models and a difference block will provide the actual solution to the question

[image]

but this is overkill ... and is using a physics engine to solve a simple linear maths question. So what about in simple Simulink blocks?

Comment: the solution shall be -9.375 watts ...Also i have the model for incandescent lamp in my block library

Comment: Well the negative is simply what are you referencing against P1 - P2 or P2 - P1.  The 9.375 figure however... why do you think it is that?

Comment: see my hand solved solution i provided in my question

Comment: I have seen it, its wrong

Comment: no its not...i am 100% sure

Comment: KNOWN: V=120V, P=75W ==> R=192R.  Voltage changes by -5V & R changes by +8R ==>  V=120-5 (115V)  & R=192+8 (200R).  Thus new power = V^2/R = 115^2/200 = 66.125.  Original power = 75W and the new power = 66.125W ==> change in power = 75W-66.125W = 8.875W  Q.E.D.

Comment: You dont count for the whole change of the power ....its continous...Hint: did you study differential equations in school ?

Comment: But that wasn't what was asked. Your last simscape question (that hasn't been closed) was open ended with additional information held back.

Comment: Yeah , i was expecting you to provide the correct simulink solution .... what i said inthe question is what i imagined shall work in Simulink .... which it seems i was wrong....but so is your model...as it doesnt give correct answer

Comment: "this" hasn't been defined. The question is quite simple. Change in power for a change in V & R.